# Fetching a PaperTrail::Version by ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

How can I fetch a PaperTrail::Version based on the ID of the version record itself?

I really need a way to get a specific version and this seems like the most direct route but cannot see any mention in the docs.

I tried `PaperTrail::Version.where_object(id: 5)` however this is returning the object with ID 5 not the Version

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure there's actually an ID on those records? From here it doesn't look like it https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/generators/paper_trail/install/templates/create_versions.rb.erb

Comment: @maxpleaner rails automatically adds an `id` unless you tell it not to [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#create_table`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table) see the `:id` and `:primary_key` options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I fetch a PaperTrail::Version based on the ID of the version record itself?

```
PaperTrail::Version.find(id)
```

`PaperTrail::Version` is a regular ActiveRecord model. PT encourages the use  of regular methods like `find` or `where`.